# Get AD Groups where the Owner is disabled with Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

This are the lines where Powershell gets all the groups in AD

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties SamAccountName, managedBy, Name, Description, GroupCategory |
Select-Object SamAccountName, @{Name = 'ManagedBy'; Expression = { (Get-ADUser -Identity $_.managedBy -Properties DisplayName).DisplayName }},Name, Description, GroupCategory
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to get only the AD groups where the owner `Enabled` property is set to `disabled`, something like the following but I cannot complete the logic

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties SamAccountName, managedBy, Name, Description, GroupCategory |
Where (Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$($_.DisplayName)'"  | Select SamAccountName, Enabled -eq "false") |
Select-Object SamAccountName, @{Name = 'ManagedBy'; Expression = { (Get-ADUser -Identity $_.managedBy -Properties DisplayName).DisplayName }},Name, Description, GroupCategory
```

EDIT:

Applying jfrmilner's answer I get the following error

```
Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'CN=example,OU=example,OU=User Archive,DC=example,DC=example' under: 'DC=example,DC=example'.
At line:2 char:18
+ Where-Object { !(Get-ADUser -Identity $_.ManagedBy).Enabled } |
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CN=exampl...,DC=example,DC=nexample:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will return only AD Groups where the ManagedBy User is Disabled:

```
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(ManagedBy=*)" -Properties ManagedBy, Description | Where-Object { !(Get-ADUser -Identity $_.ManagedBy).Enabled }
```

Comment: @BryanArreola I'd bet the error comes up for groups that don't have a defined owner.

Comment: I thought the same, but I search one of the groups that shows up in the errors and it has a value in `ManagedBy`

Comment: @BryanArreola The LDAPFilter will only return groups with a populated ManagedBy attribute. However, the ManagedBy data can be invalid, check the value exactly matches a DistinguishedName of a User.